# FIXED: Code request: Pre-populate Oppty Name

Tags: trigger, code

I've received an ask to have the **"Opportunity Name"** standard field be pre-populated when creating a new Opportunity in the format of `"Account.Name - TODAY()";` as to create a cleaner naming convention across records.  The Users create the Oppty from an Action from the Account record.

I was hoping somebody could shed some light into the code that could provide this functionality, because I was unable to find of a way within standard functionality.

Thanks!
Sean

EDIT:  Fixed with Predefined Field values within the Custom Action

Comment: Do you have Lightning Experience enabled? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98983/pre-populating-fields-at-record-creation-in-lightning-experience

Comment: If you want to standardize the naming of the Opportunity, simply create a workflow rule to rename it. The users can put anything they want and your WFR will set it to the proper format....You can default it so they do not have to enter anything at all by using URL hacking but that would require you to override the New button which you may not want to do....

Comment: Yeah - I've already though of that as well.  Unfortunately, they believe that the end-users won't like that solution

Comment: I JUST FIGURED IT OUT!  Predefined Field values within the Custom Action is the solution.  I can't believe I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do Salesforce URL Hacking to Prepopulate Fields on a Standard Page Layout

You can go through the following article

http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html

Summary:

1. Create a custom button with URL hacking url.
2. Over ride standard create opportunity button.